# What does a "course of instruction" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

Googles definition of class says "course of instruction". Would that mean a class could be something taught to a single person over a period of time?

Comment: Yes, but we wouldn't normally call that a class, so if that's the whole definition, it's dodgy.

Comment: No, a *course of instruction* doesn't imply something taught to a ***single*** person. Note that your *over a period of time* could just mean a single period (this afternoon, for example), but a "course" of instruction strongly implies ***multiple*** lessons (every afternoon next week, for example).

Comment: I suspect there is a different understanding of the word between the UK and the US. As a Canadian, I have no problem with there being a *class taught to one person*. To me, a class is a class, regardless of how many people attend. On the other hand, I think it's unusual in the UK to describe a *single* person attending a class. (I think it would more often be thought of as a series of *tutoring sessions*.)

Comment: You could teach a class or course of instruction to one person in the US, but it wouldn't be the norm. Unless someone explained it, you would assume it would be for a group of people.

Comment: To me a *class* is a group of students being taught together - by extension it can mean the course they are taking, but there still has to be a group. I'm not sure whether it's a UK/US thing, or just a difference between individual speakers. If you are taking one-on-one lessons then 99 times out of 100 they are not going to follow a syllabus that has been planned out in advance, so won't be a course - but that 100th time they will, AFAIC.

Comment: The title of this question does not match its substance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Typically**, a class, or a course, is taught to a number of students together. The words *class* and *course* **can** be applied to one-on-one instruction, but such cases are marginal; they are not what one first thinks of when one hears these words. The words are most likely to be applied to one-on-one instruction in the contexts in which the similarities between such instruction and the instruction in groups are more relevant than the differences. For example, a student who says 'I am taking four classes this term', may be including in that number a ‘reading course’ or an ‘independent study project’ that he is taking alone—this is because the one-on-one character of that class is irrelevant to the point of the communication (which is about his workload or the total academic credit earned).